# Default width and height of Matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib

What is the default height and width of any Matplotlib figure, in inches?

I haven't found any info regarding this on the official website (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html)

Any references would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [documentation site you link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html) to we find

[image]

or in text form

> `figsize` : 2-tuple of floats, default: rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6.4, 4.8]
>            Figure dimension (width, height) in inches.